# Project field not exist by default value

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I want to project a not exist field to the default value

CollectionA

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("6013859ba0c3120034d08bfa"),
  name: "A1",
  refs:[
   {id: ObjectId("6013859ba0c3120034d08bfb"), text: "ABC"},
   {id: ObjectId("6013859ba0c3120034d08bfc"), text: "DEF"}
  ]
}
```

CollectionB

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("6013859ba0c3120034d08bfb"),
  name: "B1",
  altName: "b1"
}

{
  _id: ObjectId("6013859ba0c3120034d08bfc"),
  name: "B2"
}
```

Expected output

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6013859ba0c3120034d08bfa"),
    "name" : "A1",
    "refs" : [ 
        {
            "id" : ObjectId("6013859ba0c3120034d08bfb"),
            "text" : "ABC",
            "name" : "B1",
            "altName" : "b1"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : ObjectId("6013859ba0c3120034d08bfc"),
            "text" : "DEF",
            "name" : "B2",
            "altName" : "Unspecified"
        }
    ]
}
```

In my case, I just want to do this in project expression.
I tried with `$project` like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70045246/lookup-on-array-of-objects)

```
{
    $project: {
      ...,
        altName: {
          $first: { $ifNull: [ "$$refsB.altName", "Unspecified" ] }
        },
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: So you are inserting the documents with the default value for the non-specific field(s)? Or for projection? If it is for projection, your aggregation query works.

Comment: for projection @YongShun. I don't want to insert the document with default value.
The example code, I got it from the mongo page
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/

Comment: Hmmm, I still not sure what is your problem. As you get the answer that `$ifNull` to do what you needs. Check this [demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7OzV9WiAKD9)

Comment: sorry for my mistake. I just update the question @YongShun.
the data structure like in the question what you answer me before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to retrieve the `refsB.altName` value via `$first` **first**, then with `$ifNull` to check and assign value if it is null.

```
altName: {
  $ifNull: [
    {
      $first: "$refsB.altName"
    },
    "Unspecified"
  ]
}
```

> Complete query

```
db.collectionA.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$refs"
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "collectionB",
      "localField": "refs.id",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "refsB"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      name: 1,
      refs: {
        id: "$refs.id",
        text: "$refs.text",
        name: {
          $first: "$refsB.name"
        },
        altName: {
          $ifNull: [
            {
              $first: "$refsB.altName"
            },
            "Unspecified"
          ]
        },
        
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      name: {
        $first: "$name"
      },
      refs: {
        $push: "$refs"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Cu66PNZ-ESD)